# BufferredWriter to write thousands of lines

Tags: java

I am getting results from sql and writing each record as a line to a file using BufferdWriter. The no of records will be in thousands(more than 40000 chars).

### Code:

```
Iterator<SyncDetail> it = details.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    detail = it.next();
    sbRec = formatStringFile(detail);
    m_logger.info(sbRec.toString());
    strRec = sbRec.toString();
    bw.write(strRec);
    bw.newLine();
}
bw.close();
```

Now My question is:
This code is giving correct result. But after every 4096 chars, an unexpected new line char is coming in the resulted file. May I know why is this and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Great, now what? You're experiencing a problem I guess?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @OP Don't get discouraged only because your question is on-hold. Feel free to [[edit]] your post with more details (don't forget to include sentence with `?` at the end), and this post should be reopened soon.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Now I editted my question. Please have a look at and respond with your valuble suggestions.

Comment: A new line is written with bw.newLine(). Are you getting 2 consecutive new lines? If so did you check if sbRec.toString() ends with a new line?

Comment: I am getting this new lin char exactly after every 4096 chars. For ex: if 4096 char is 'n' in the word jantarc, I am getting a new line char exactly after n like jan \n tarc.

Comment: sbRec.toString() how much is long? is it of a fixed size?

Comment: sbRec.toString() will not cross 100 char limit.